# Use different webservers for REST interface and HTML?

Tags: rest, web-servers

An application provides a REST interface to offer status and statistics information.

```
localhost:1111/stats -> return JSON encoded statistics
localhost:1111/status -> return JSON encoded system status
```

Now, the user also wants to see the results nicely presented in an HTML page, for example under

```
localhost:1111
localhost:1111/index.html
```

It would also be possible that the user sets a field in the request header to request HTML instead of JSON, so `localhost:1111/status` serves either JSON or HTML based on the request header. This solution should not be part of the discussion.

I'd like to know, if, from a software engineering perspective, it is a good design to

- a) Keep the endpoints the way they are
- b) Serve JSON under `localhost:1111/json/{stats,status,...}` and serve the HTML frontend under root
- c) Spin up a whole new webserver for the HTML page (as in `localhost:2222`) and use the REST interface from a)

Edit: I guess it does not matter for the overall decision, but I am using embedded web servers.

Comment: This is exactly what Content Negotiation is for. Why do you exclude that?

Comment: Because the semantics are different. One (JSON) is pure data, the other includes layout (the user wants a complete website, not just an HTML table with the data fields). Maybe thats fine with Content Negotiation, but personally I don't want to use is as such. The requested content type can differentiate between JSON, XML, plain text, even binary data (the data format) - but the content itself should stay the same. Just my opinion though.

Comment: A URI identifies a *resource*. The resource is an abstract model. As long as that abstract model is the same, it should use the same URI, IMO. Of course, a representation of that resource intended for consumption by humans will look different than a representation of that same resource intended for consumption by machines.

Comment: I'm totally in favour of deploying a different process (web server) to publish static content (including SPAs). However, If these HTML are not static content, if they are just a different format of the same resource representantation, then Jörg is absolutly right. Use content negotiation and forget the 2nd server.

Answer (score 2):

A mix-up.

- A REST Web API supporting *application/json* and *text/html* formats (as Jörg [suggested](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/386191/use-different-webservers-for-rest-interface-and-html/386385#comment849638_386191))
- An HTTP Server supplying the static content (docs, files, scripts, SPAs, CDN, whatever).
- An HTTP Server as Reverse Proxy

Placing the REST API and the HTTP Server behind the *Reverse Proxy* removes the CORS overhead and provide us with a single entry point for balancing.

Segregating REST API and the static content server allows us to scale up/out and deploy them separately. Both could use their respective root contexts, what simplifies the reverse proxy set up. Through the reverse proxy, we implement different subcontexts for each process.

```
HTTP Srv [1-n) / <-- reverse --> /index.html
REST Api [1-n) / <-- reverse --> /api/status
```

The segregation also releases the REST API from delivering static content what leaves all the resources for what matters, the business.

It might seem oversized (I don't deny it), but I have found the segregation of concerns to make a big deal when it comes to distributed applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would wote on C because of:

- departing frontend from backend you allows for easy replacement one frontend by another, coexistence of many frontend versions, hosting frontend from other server than backend

b is not in agreement with REST, your decision about content negotiations is better

a current state of routing is acceptable, everything depends from number of routes, you can have single page with departed routing for client only access by JavaScript in browser, it can be other routing than routing on backend that servers resources

Summary. A with content negotiations is great for projekt with one primary frontend. You can connect another's too.

B is not recommend.

C is great if any frontend are equal and you want to decouple your code in easy way. Crud REST interface is not always best interface for end user.

Comment: Option B is quite common, actually, when you have the API tree starting under `https://server/api`, while the root holds a web app that need not be structured along the same areas as the API.

Comment: I agree that this is a common case, but still, it is not recommended by me because of the pure REST point of view. For example in tutorial https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/rest/project-routing in 3:00 there is presented an idea of usage depart routing for api.